# Configure email server on AWS EC2 with SmarterMail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, email-server

I'm trying to move an email server we have using SmarterMail to AWS.
I've provisioned a new EC2 instance using W2016, installed the software and assigned a new Elastic IP.
I've opened ports for what I think it's required as in:

[image]

But still don't receive any emails there. Any ideas on what I might be missing?

---

I've just got this answer from Amazon after submitting the form here
https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request?catalog=true&isauthcode=true

> To assist, we have checked and confirmed that there are no email
>   sending limitations on your account. Additionally, we also tried to
>   configure the rDNS entry for disgrafic.es as 52.28.13.199, however
>   this attempt failed.
>
> The mapping for this reverse DNS entry is failing because the PTR
>   record doesn't match the A record for that domain. We currently
>   require the forward A record to match the PTR record for all reverse
>   DNS entries.
>
> You can either provide us with an alternate hostname, or configure the
>   A record for this domain to match the desired PTR record on your side.

Looks quite strange to me this thing. If so that basically means I can't have a server for the web (with the @ and www domains) and a server for the email.
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What’s the domain name you want to receive mail for? It may be misconfigured.

Comment: The name disgrafic.es doesn't resolve to 52.28.13.199 in the DNS. It instead resolves to 80.58.162.95. This is the bit that amazon is talking about in this message.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this is exactly what I'm saying; the base domain and www should not point to this machine, instead they resolve to the webserver. That's my complaint above: I can't seem to have my web on one server and email on a different one IF I want to have the naked domain resolve for the web server

Comment: Then why are you trying to use that name? Use a different name. maybe `mail.dnsgrafic.es`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you define an A record for your `Amazon Elastic IP`, for example mail.mydomain.com? This is used to set up a `Reverse DNS` on your web server, so that other `SMTP servers` know that you’re not a spam relay.

Then add an `MX record` to the address you just defined, for example mail.mydomain.com. Now each `SMTP server` sending mail to mydomain.com will contact mail.domain.com, which in turn points to your `EC2` instance.

Also, keep in mind AWS limits email sent from `EC2` by default. You need to have them remove that limit: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Are_there_any_limitations_in_sending_email_from_EC2_instances

Similarly, contact AWS to let them know what `Elastic IP` Addresses you are going to use for your mail servers so that they can have them White-listed with SpamHaus and others.

Comment: I think my DNS is correctly configured. This is what I have there:
mail    A       52.28.13.199  
@      MX  10  mail.disgrafic.es   
@      TXT     v=spf1 a mx ip4:52.28.13.199 -all

Just sent the form you suggested on the previous reply. I tried again this morning sending email there and nothing happened.

Intersting thing is that from this domain I can send email to hotmail for example. The problem seems to be on receiving.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the domain `disgrafic.es` and the DNS seems to be fine.

However the IP `52.28.13.199` only accepts traffic on port 80 and times out on all the other ports listed in your Security Group.

Since the ports are open in the *Security Group* I assume that you've got a local **Windows firewall** turned on and that blocks the incoming connections on all the email-related ports. Check that and open the ports in the Windows firewall too.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I thought that the changes I made on the AWS security group reflected on the Windows Firewall. Is that not true?

Comment: @vmasanas Nope, these are independent firewalls. One is Windows internal and one is AWS, external from Windows. You have to open the ports in both.